# req.body comes back empty in node.js and express app

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am learning node.js with express. I am pretty new, and this is my first project with absolutely no tutorials.

The app will use ejs for templates and I am using express.json() to parse the data from the form. Not using body-parser since express does this out of the box now.

Whenever I console.log(req.body) it comes in as an empty string. When I try to console.log(req.body.name), or any other of the form fields, it comes back as undefined.

Please help, I have no idea what the issue is, and this has never been a problem with any of my previous practice apps.

Here is my relavant code:

in app.js

```
// Require routes
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
//
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// 
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

In my form (register.ejs):

```
<form action="/users/register" method="POST">
    <div class="formGroup">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name">
    </div>
    <div class="formGroup">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter any username">
    </div>
    <div class="formGroup">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
    </div>
    <div class="formGroup">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <div class="formGroup">
        <label for="password2">Confirm password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password2">
    </div>
    <div class="formGroup">
        <label for="about">About</label>
        <textarea name="about" placeholder="Say a little bit about yourself..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="formGroup">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

In my route file (users.js)

```
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {

  console.log(req.body);

  const newUser = {
    name: req.body.name,
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    about: req.body.about
  }
  console.log(newUser);
  res.redirect('/users');
});
```

Thank you for any response!

Answer (score 0):

You need a middleware to parse the request body. I think the most common one is [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser). It's pretty easy to use:

- Install it with: `npm install body-parser`
- Import it: `var bodyParser = require('body-parser')`
- And register as a express middleware: `app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))`

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, as far as I know, the newest version of express no longer requires body-parser. It can do it out of the box with express.json(). I have done this with two other apps and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

WELL! This is embarrassing. I just restarted my server and it was working. I don't know why it wasn't working before. I am thinking it may be because I thought I was using nodemon when I wasn't. Good thing I showed how much of a noob I am with my first post haha.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the front,
I saw your code and there might be some mistakes that you had to pay attention.

You have to install bodyParser `npm install body-parser --save`

```
`// Require routes
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
//
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// 
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);`
```

And in the form (in `register.ejs` file), `action="/users/register"` is used, so you have to include the route `/users` in your `users.js` file because the route in `post('/register' ...` should be same with `action="/users/register"`.